# focusout only fires on document load and never again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-focusout

I've got a fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/pneebntd/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#Address').focusout(ValidateAddress($(this).val(), "address"));
    $('#City').focusout(ValidateAddress($(this).val(), "city"));
    $('#State').focusout(ValidateAddress($(this).val(), "state"));
    $('#Zipcode').focusout(ValidateAddress($(this).val(), "zip/postal code"));
    $("#StateList").change(ValidateAddress($(this).val(), "state"));
});

function ValidateAddress(location, label) {
     console.info("made it there : " + location + " " + label);
}
```

The short of it is that I'm (trying) to attach the event handler for a function I want to run when a control loses its focus (or when a dropdown changes value).

The way it's written, it fires on page load but never again after that. I've done this before but maybe it's just because it's Monday but... what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Read the documentation for [focusout](http://api.jquery.com/focusout/).

Comment: I wonder why someone downvoted the question. It has a running example, explains what went wrong and what the expected behavior is. Just because it's a silly mistake, it doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code

```
$('#Address').focusout(ValidateAddress($(this).val(), "address"));
```

*calls* `ValidateAddress` and passes its return value into `focusout`, exactly the way `foo(bar())` *calls* `bar` and passes its return value into `foo`.

If you want to give a function to `focusout`, you have to do that instead. For instance:

```
$('#Address').focusout(function() {
    ValidateAddress($(this).val(), "address");
});
```

That code creates a new anonymous function and passes that function reference into `focusout`. When the event occurs, it will call your `ValidateAddress` function.

Comment: Shouldn't jQuery complain when you pass something that is not a function into an event handler setting function?

Comment: I swear, some days I just shouldn't even touch the keyboard. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @JuanMendes: The check probably isn't worth the overhead. For instance, my guess is that `ValidateAddress` has no `return` in it at all. So calling it results in `undefined`. So we're passing `undefined` into `focusout`. That's a **lot** like calling `focusout` without any arguments, which is supposed to *trigger* the event. Checking would require using the `arguments` pseudo-array, like this: `if (!handler && arguments.length > 0)`. In addition to being bloat they just don't need in such a large lib, on some engines using `arguments` within a function *markedly* slows the function down.

Comment: I guess I didn't think of the fact that not passing arguments is also a valid case.